# DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55195/devtools/browser/a6ac454e-4906-4205-8d15-2b89fd8c4396

Tags: python, powershell, selenium-webdriver

I have made a python bot for instagram automation and I'm running it with selenium with web driver but I'm getting error in powershell saying: "DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55195/devtools/browser/a6ac454e-4906-4205-8d15-2b89fd8c4396"

[image]

I want to run the file to do instagram automation.